# Struggling with a query, join, in

Tags: mysql, join

I am struggling with a query. And wondering if someone could help.

I have a table of tags (service request tickets)
and a table of serial numbers

From my tags I am doing this

```
Select * from tag 
where
tag.created
BETWEEN '2012-9-01'
AND '2012-12-29' 
and
tag.tagtype <> 'service'
```

Now,
i would like to join with serialnumber (table) where
(not sure inner/outer or just join)

tag.serialnumberid is in serialnumber.id
and serialnumber .modelid = 80

I am thinking it should be easy.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select * from tag 
join serialnumber on tag.serialnumberid = serialnumber.id
where
   tag.created BETWEEN '2012-9-01' AND '2012-12-29' 
     and
  tag.tagtype <> 'service'
     and serialnumber.modelid = 80;
```